# Using SCSS @extend from within <style> with global scss import

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, sass, bootstrap-vue

Using `vue-cli` I've created a project with `Bootstrap` and `Bootstrap-vue`.

I've created a vue.config.js and am using `prependData` to load my `theme.scss` file like so:

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: `@import "./scss/theme.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
};
```

My theme.scss:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap-reboot.scss';

$theme-colors: (
  primary: #2D3047,
  success: #0FBD72,
  danger: #AE2029,
  light: #F6F5F3,
  dark: #23201B,
);

@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
@import '~bootstrap-vue/src/index.scss';
```

This gives me access to variables, functions, and mixins when using `<style lang="scss">` from a vue component as intended.

However, if I try to use for example:

```
#foo {
  @extend .pt-5;
  color: var(--light)
}
```

without first having `@import "bootstrap";` at the top of my `<style>` tag vue will throw an error stating that it can't extend `.pt-5` as the class doesn't exist.

So, my question is: using the above global import for scss, how can I use the `@extend` directive in component `<style>` tags without needing to re-import bootstrap in each component's `<style>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks good to me. If you are sure of your path `./scss/theme.scss";`, in the vue.config.js file, there are only two other things I can think of, that could prevent you from using `@extend`, without importing the scss file above the `style` tag

- The file where the `pt-5` utility class resides was not imported into `theme.scss`.
- You didn't stop your server and restart it after making the changes to `vue.config.js`.

Comment: When I sat down this morning to look at it it was working. The only thing I can think of is that I didn't restart the server when I thought I had. Marking your answer as correct, thanks for the reply.